Azure Devops Server Cannot customize process settings
I’ve joined a company that wants to make changes to their TFS, but they don’t know who the USER Admin is. Additionally, we are missing the Fields tab. It appears that everything is locked, and we are unable to edit anything. Currently, I can’t edit the State or Fields.
We’ve tried everything possible to add my user to the Admin group, including checking the database, but we haven’t been successful.
I’d really appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.
Thanks in advance!
collection setting >> process

